# Unable to Install New Theme. Dashboard goes blank

Tags: magento-1.8, php, theme, helper

I m running a magento site with default theme and products loading at the main page. Now i m trying to get new theme for which i copied app/themename directory to `app/design/frontend/default` and skin/themename to `skin/frontend/default`, also did i copy `app/code/local` to `app/code/` and other stuff like `etc/modules/*` and `js/*` to magento site appropriate directory.

Now i went to `System -> Design` and selected the theme which i copied. Then i cleared the cache and logged out. The next time i login into the admin panel, my panel goes blank and the error msg is get from apache logs is `Class 'Megnor_Framework_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php`. Not only that my site doesn't load images with grid/list, but css is good.

Then i did some trial by removing local and followed the same procedure. Now i m back with my admin panel but my site still doesn't load images and this time my apache logs gives me this `Class 'Mage_Framework_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php`

Not knowing further what to do

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like somewhere in your project you have `Mage::helper('framework')` or `Mage::helper("framework");` which can't load the helper.

I would imagine looking at your steps that you had a module residing in `app/code/local/Megnor/Framework` which was declaring helpers using the shortname `framework` but the file `app/code/local/Megnor/Framework/Helper/Data.php` didn't exist or wasn't readable by your web server. This explains the error `Class 'Megnor_Framework_Helper_Data' not found in app/Mage.php`.

If you then removed the module files, but there was still an attempt to load the helper in one of your templates, Magento would attempt to load `Mage_Framework_Helper_Data` instead since the shortname wouldn't be conversted to `Megnor_Framework_Helper` anymore.

Long story short, search for the helper calls mentioned on my first line in your `app/design` folder. If it's there, you'll need to make a determination on whether you can remove these lines, or whether you need to attempt to succesfully install the module `Megnor_Framework`.

Comment: I created a new file and added code from following link http://savekro.com/test/app/code/local/Megnor/Framework/etc/adminhtml.xml. These resulted into a new error `Megnor_AdvancedMenu_Helper_Data`. Can we get any idea from it.

Comment: It sounds like you have a bunch of modules missing from `app/etc/local/Megnor/`.

Comment: Perhaps I could find all the modules under `app/etc/local/Megnor/`, just that they are not being called/used.

Answer (score 0):

Blank admin page could happen if you have compilation on and install new stuff.

Have you disabled compilation first?

EDIT:
Not sure how it is in 1.8.0 as I use 1.9.1. But in 1.9.1 theme should go in

`app/design/frontend/THEME/VERSION`

and *not* in

`app/design/frontend/default/THEME/VERSION`

Similarly for skin and modules.

Have you triple checked these?

Comment: Yes, compilation is disabled

Comment: Ok, I have edited my answer with some more info you might want to check.

Comment: Sorry checked it, but the files should go in `app/design/frontend/default` only